# Is there a function to save multiple csv files with different names in python?

Tags: python, pandas, function

I am trying to write a function in python that essentially splits the original CSV file into multiple csv files and saves their names. The code that I have written so far looks like this:

```
def split_data(a, b, name_of_the_file):
    part = df.loc[a:b-1]
    filename = str(name_of_the_file)
    part.to_csv(r'C:\path\to\file\filename.csv', index=False)
```

The main intention of the code is to name each file a different name, which is the input (name_of_the_file). The code seems to work, but only saves the file as filename.csv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is saving the file(s) with the name `filename.csv` because you only specify that name in the following line:

```py
part.to_csv(r'C:\path\to\file\filename.csv', index=False)
```

To change the name you need to change the string to take the `filename` variable:

```py
part.to_csv(f'C:\path\to\file\{filename}.csv', index=False)
```

Notice how the string has a `f` in the beginning of it -- this is called an `f-string` and it allows you to add Python variables directly into the string by using curly brackets (`{filename}`).

Comment: You can do raw-strings and format-strings simultaneously like this: `rf'C:\path\to\file\{filename}.csv'`. If you miss this, python will parse '\t' as a tab character, etc.

Comment: Did you add a `f` before the quotations of the string? It should be: `f'C:\path\to\file\{filename}.csv'`, and not `'C:\path\to\file\{filename}.csv'`.

Comment: Glad it did! Make sure to mark either my or @Christian's answer as correct via the green marker next to the answers to mark your question as answered for the rest of the board.

Comment: Could you please tell me where the green marker is? I couldn't find it.

Comment: Left off the answers, underneath the up/down votes.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow.

I think what you need to do is to user string interpolation.

https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/string-interpolation

Example from the linked page:

```
name = 'World'
program = 'Python'
print(f'Hello {name}! This is {program}')
```

In your case something like

```
def split_data(a, b, name_of_the_file):
    part = df.loc[a:b-1]
    filename = str(name_of_the_file)
    part.to_csv(r'C:\path\to\file\{filename}.csv', index=False)
```

I have added the curly braces to your code as in my initial example.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I tried doing this, but now, the file is being saved as {name_of_the_file}. It is not taking in my input name.

Comment: Yes. Do you think it could because of my input? Looks something like this:
split_data(8, 999, 'some_name')
But still getting saved as {filename}

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to saving multiple csv files

```
# create a list of dataframes (example below assumes a dictionary of dataframes)
lst_of_dfs = [x for x in dfs]

# path to save files
path = 'c:/location_to_save_files/'

# create a list of filenames you would like to use
fnames = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']

# output the data
# this outputs the files using the index, i, + fnames
for i, j in enumerate(fnames, 0):
    lst_of_dfs[i].to_csv(path'+str(i)+str(j)+'.csv')
```